# Always connected to CPU on google-colab. GPU available only with python 2

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

In google colab GPU seems to be available only with python 2. with python 3 i have pulled all stops but in vain

1. I have changed the runtime from edit > notebook settings to python 3 and GPU
2. I have changed the runtime from runtime > connect to runtime as well
3. I have connected and reconnected to google-client using

`!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software properties module-init-tools` (For some reason i cannot get this line in code format along with rest below)

```
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

as directed by [this blog](https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d)

i connected to runtime via 1 and 2 above before running 3 and after 3

i am consistently getting

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()

output: ''
```

and :

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()

output:
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 17193406649657173379]
```

Any help on how to connect to GPU runtime?

Answer (score 0):

When I've used Colaboratory's GPU, it's never shown in the device list. If you just run a Tensorflow session it will automatically use the GPU unless told otherwise.

Comment: Does your runtime keep disconnecting as well? i have never been able to use colab's gpu for more than 1 hour in a stretch. it disconnects

Comment: Nah, I got a stable 12 hours the other night. I've noticed if the connection drops for even a second though it doesn't try to auto-reconnect or anything. I disconnected when switching from Ethernet to WiFi a couple of times. When I'm running a long experiment, I put a few lines that upload the results to Google Drive at the end of the cell just in case.